# JSON and HTML trying to understand

Tags: json, xml

According to a post on Stackflow.com called “what’s is JSOn and why would I use it? “web services used XML as their primary data format for transmitting back data, but since JSON appeared, it is preferred method.” Why do must web services use JSON over XML, is because it’s a better method for interchanging?

Answer (score 2):

XML was designed primarily for document formats, e.g. papers in scientific journals. It contains many features that aren't needed for simple data interchange, and these features can get in the way when you are processing XML because they can't be easily represented in Javascript. So the code for processing the XML ends up a lot more complicated than it could be. By contrasts, JSON has an exact match to the data structures Javascript can handle natively. Of course, that problem could in principle be solved by using a language with better XML support than JavaScript - XSLT, for example - but unfortunately XSLT in the browser has never had the same level of investment put into it.

Additionally, for reasons I have never understood, the browser security folks decided that reading JSON from alien web sites (i.e. from a different domain from your HTML page) is safe, but reading XML from alien sites isn't. So if you switch from XML to JSON, you get rid of a lot of cross-site-scripting hassle.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is less verbose and it is sufficient for simple data transmission, i.e. if you do not need any transformations (XSLT).